# MPAndroidChart / CombinedChart - bar always starts at zero

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I have a CombinedChart with several lines and one bar, and even my lines started to draw in negative numbers, the bar always start in zero.

How can I draw the barChart according the begin of the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar cannot cover the area below zero because **that just would not be correct behaviour** of a barchart.

If you add an entry with value 30 on the y-axis, it should cover exactly a range of 30 on the y-axis, and not 30 + whatever space is left to the bottom. That is simply not correct.

In case you still want to have the bars to fill the whole screen, you can "cheat" and use stacked bars with 2 values. The first value represents the "starting point" of the bar, and the second value the actual value.

```
// e.g. -100 starting point, 30 actual value
// covered area is -100 to 30 on the y-axis
BarEntry stackedEntry = new BarEntry(new float[] {-100, 30}, xIndex);
```